# ¿Cómo se pueden emparejar 2 columnas del mismo nombre en una dataframe en Python? Uso de libreria pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ordenamiento, agrupación

Digamos que tengo la siguiente `df`:

```
       0       1     2      3       4     5       0                1        2         3     4        5
0  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None     None
1  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None    Arena
2  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None   Marron
3  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None  Purpura
4  Fondo  Cuerpo  Ojos  Color  Pinzas  Puas  Oceano  Cuerpo cangrejo  Antenas  Amarillo  None    Verde
```

¿Cómo hago para que las columnas del mismo nombre queden ordenadas así?

```
       0      0      1               1    2       2     3        3      4    4    5     5         
0  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas None            
1  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Arena     
2  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Marron    
3  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Purpura    
4  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Verde
```

Además, ¿cómo sería en caso de que las columnas a agrupar fuesen n (un número grande)? Se asume que siempre se llamarían de la forma en como se muestra arriba.

Comment: No me queda claro la estructura del dataframe, podrías crear una tabla en vez de ponerlo como código?

Answer (score 0):

Ya

```
In [460]: res.sort_index(1, inplace=True)

In [461]: res

Out[461]: 

       0       0       1                1     2        2      3         3       4     4     5        5
0  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas     None
1  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas    Arena
2  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas   Marron
3  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas  Purpura
4  Fondo  Oceano  Cuerpo  Cuerpo cangrejo  Ojos  Antenas  Color  Amarillo  Pinzas  None  Puas    Verde
```